# Prove that the space of real-valued continuous differentiable functions $C^1(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to show that $C^1(\mathbb R)$ is a vector space. I know there are multiple similar questions like this already but I haven't found one that really answers my question. In order to show that this is a vector space I need to check all 8 axioms  similar to here: [Prove all 8 axioms of a vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133260/prove-all-8-axioms-of-a-vector-space?rq=1)

It is pretty simple to show that if $f,g \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ then $f+g \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ since $D(f+g)=Df+Dg$ and $f,g$ were assumed to be cts. differentiable.

My problem is "proving" the commutative and associative property. Aren't these two properties trivial? For example, isn't it trivial that $f+g=g+f$?

Comment: It depends how deep into an axiomatic proof you want to go. I look at the commutative and associative property and think they are trivial personally, but it depends on what groundwork you have built up and what level of detail you need to provide

Comment: @NickGuerrero I am often not sure what I can assume and what can be "brushed off" as trivial. I doubt we have to go that deep in to axiomatic proofs since it's a very applied math oriented course. I just wasn't sure if I was missing some obvious proof.

Comment: Well, then you probably just need the amount of detail in @Keshav s answer below. Thats how I would do it at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to go into detail, you would say something like, at each point $x$,
$$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+ g(x) = g(x) + f(x) = (g+f)(x),$$
where the first and last equalities come from the definition of the sum of functions. As José mentioned, it boils down to the fact that the respective laws hold for real numbers.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since they hold in the space of *all* functions from *any* set into $\mathbb R$, then, in particular, they hold in the context within which you are working. And they are a trivial consequence of the fact that they hold for numbers.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense! Thanks for your help.